# Installer crashes when installing Ubuntu 18.04.5 on vmware workstation 16

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, vmware

II am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04.5 into a VMWare Workstation 16 VM.  It starts up the installer and just after the "Installing kernel" step it flashed a installer failed message and starts over.

I was able to install the desktop version without an issue.

One thing I noticed is that one of the panels says I have an Installer update available.  It says it is using 20.07.1+git2.5de9df3e and can update to version 21.01.2.  Should it be those numbers when installing 18.04.5?

Answer (score 0):

This just in.  Seems that the 18.04.5 install iso attempts to load the 20.07.1 installer automagically.  This, of course is a recipe for a crash.  In order to install, I had to turn the network adapter off so that it could not update the installer.  Smells like a bug to me.

Comment: There is no 20.07.1. Do you mean 20.04.1 or 20.10? If it's a bug that you've found, please [report it on Launchpad](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs#Filing_bugs_manually_at_Launchpad.net) 

Comment: I believe it said 20.07.01, but that's for the installer, not the OS.  I'll report the bug in the morning and let the experts decide.

Comment: Confirmed, It is running installer 20.07.1+git2.5de9df3e.